# No such event: 1

Tags: zsh

I have the following `$HOME/.zshrc` file:

```
[vagrant@devel]/vagrant% cat ~/.zshrc
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
if [ $(history | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
  # we've just shelled in; "magically" cd into the vagrant shared folder
  cd "/vagrant"
fi
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

I'm using the same script with Bash and it works just fine; on initial login, the user has no history and is magically transported to `/vagrant`.

When I log in to this box with this `$HOME/.zshrc`, I see the following error:

```
/home/vagrant/.zshrc:fc:3: no such event: 1
[vagrant@devel]/vagrant%
```

I do not know what this means and Google isn't leading me to a result. Apparently the code works, but this appears to be some kind of error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need `#!/usr/bin/env zsh` in `~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `history` builtin command and count the lines.

You can just check `HISTCMD` variable being zero in your `~/.zshrc`. `HISTCMD`  represents current command sequence number in history.

So your `~/.zshrc` can be simply this:

```
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
if [[ $HISTCMD -eq 0 ]]; then
  # we've just shelled in; "magically" cd into the vagrant shared folder
  cd "/vagrant"
fi
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, `zsh`'s `history` command emits errors when there is no history, so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
if [ $(history 2>/dev/null | wc -l) -eq 0 ]; then
  # we've just shelled in; "magically" cd into the vagrant shared folder
  cd "/vagrant"
fi
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

No more errors.